# How can I simulate android traffic to a web link?

Tags: android

I have a web link that tracks the UDID, device model, screen size, browser type etc.

How can I simulate traffic from an android device to access this link, but to simulate the UDID, device model etc parameters?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? do you need to get device id from android devices?

Comment: yes we need the device id. This ID needs to be simulated (generated).

Comment: If you are doing only simulation then may be you can send a random generated character sequence each time you are sending data to the web service so every time you send data it will be unique and the service will think it's a new device each time.